# About the failure in making MSI installer

Tags: wix

I'm making a installer, a strange issue was on my way.

I use a custom action to call the sc.exe to install my service, and the MSI is already built.
But If i click the installer to install, the installation failed, the log says that the sc.exe  installation failed.

But the wired thing is that if I use a CMD in administrator privilege and use msiexec to run the installer, it'll succeed.

Why?

Comment: Why don't you use ServiceInstall element? http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/serviceinstall.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In question itself you have answered your question.
Windows vista onward by default runs most applications with least privilege access (non-admin) in an attempt to keep both malicious virus code and inexperienced end users from damaging the system.As your application is trying to modify the system, it needs to be elevated to Admin privilege in order to run successfully.
Go through [Services permissions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782435%28WS.10%29.aspx).
To run your custom action with elevated privileges set Impersonate as No and Execute in custom action as deferred.deferred Indicates that the custom action runs in-script (possibly with elevated privileges).[refer this for more info](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2007/07/12/immediate-custom-actions-always-impersonate.aspx).
Let Me know if it worked for you

Comment: Thanks, use Impersonate do fix my problem